# How to keep Supervising Route Controller running in Apache Camel Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I try to use *Supervising Route Controller* as described in [Camel documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/route-controller.html#_configuring_supervising_route_controller) to retry starting routes if fail on startup.

I have following lines in my `application.properties` file:

```
camel.springboot.route-controller-supervise-enabled=true
camel.springboot.route-controller-initial-delay=5000
camel.springboot.route-controller-back-off-delay=5000
camel.springboot.route-controller-back-off-max-attempts=10
camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true
```

On starting the application all the routes get started and stopped imediatelly as if the option `camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true` was not present.

```
...
2023-07-13T08:54:49.470+02:00  INFO 25984 --- [  restartedMain] c.b.c.l.LdapIntegrationApplication       : Started LdapIntegrationApplication in 13.596 seconds (process running for 17.256)
2023-07-13T08:54:49.507+02:00  WARN 25984 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.a.c.s.boot.SpringBootCamelContext      : CamelContext has only been running for less than a second. If you intend to run Camel for a longer time then you can set the property camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true in application.properties or add spring-boot-starter-web JAR to the classpath.
2023-07-13T08:54:49.509+02:00  INFO 25984 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 4.0.0-M3 (LdapCamel) is shutting down (timeout:45s)
2023-07-13T08:54:49.524+02:00  INFO 25984 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Routes stopped (stopped:4)
...
```

How can I keep the *Supervising Route Controller* running?

Comment: I got exactly the same behavior, it seems `camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true` is ignored

Comment: the only solution i found is to include spring-boot-starter-web in the pom.xml.
Unfortunately it means a tomcat is started, and keep the application running. it's ugly.